# Current-controlled PWM Generator with variable duty cycle?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, switching

I need to implement a variable duty cycle PWM generator with constant frequency (100kHz) to help drive a MOSFET. Is there such a thing out there in the market or is it something I need to build with other parts? I am fairly new to power electronics so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use a 555 ic

Comment: I thought the frequency varied with the duty cycle for the 555, or no?

Comment: you can either vary duty - fixed freq, or vary freq - fixed duty, or sort of vary both...http://www.electroschematics.com/5834/pulse-generator-with-555/

Comment: Thank You. I was looking up some and I notice there's two types- voltage mode and current mode. I've read some of the differences between them, but they don't adequately explain whether or not I can control the PWM with current? The answer may seem obvious but which one do should I go with?

Answer (score 1):

You can either buy an IC, check TL494 IC or use a microcontroller to generate PWM. I have personally worked with microcontroller PIC18f2420 to generate PWM and it works fine. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

It should be an easy circuit to implement. Just search for a microcontroler with native PWM output, and a gate driver IC to turn ON and OFF the MOSFET (International Rectifier has a lot of them).